# SQL Server : calling a stored procedure using table data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I may be wording this question very poorly but I am not 100% sure what I need to question.

I am trying to iterate over rows in a table and call a stored procedure using the data from the rows.

This is the code I already have, the problem with this is a timing issue (1000 rows takes around 1 minute);

```
--Set up a temp table with all non email alerts
SELECT TOP(1000)
    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AlertID),
    a.*, i.ImgData
INTO 
    #temp
FROM 
    dbo.ALERTS a 
JOIN 
    dbo.IMAGES i ON i.VehicleID = a.VehicleID
WHERE 
    a.EmailImageSent = 0 OR a.EmailSent = 0

DECLARE @MaxRownum INT
SET @MaxRownum = (SELECT MAX(RowNum) FROM #temp)

DECLARE @Iter INT
SET @Iter = (SELECT MIN(RowNum) FROM #temp)

DECLARE @ImgData VARBINARY(MAX)

WHILE @Iter <= @MaxRownum
BEGIN    
    SELECT @VehicleID = VehicleID, @ImgData = ImgData
    FROM #temp
    WHERE RowNum = @Iter

    IF @ImgData IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        EXEC dbo.someProcedure @VehicleID, @ImgData
        --SELECT 'Image data found for', @VehicleID, @ImgData
    END

    SET @Iter = @Iter + 1
END

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Is there anyway I can run the stored procedure (`dbo.someProcedure`) while using a set based statement as the input?

Sorry if this has been asked before, I've had a look and couldn't find an answer or if this question isn't informative enough.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Join the table inside the stored proc ,instead of passing each time an id...

Comment: a temp table is visible in scope to a called procedure, so create the temp table in the outer procedure, then just check for the existence of the temp table in the called procedure just to make sure and access it like you ordinarily would.

Comment: You can also look at table valued parameters.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you ever find yourself doing things "one at a time" (i.e. loops or cursors) in SQL, you are probably doing it wrong. Think about processing sets of data instead. If you can show us what "dbo.someprocedure" does, we can probably help you rewrite it to process all the rows at once.

Comment: What does the stored procedure do, anyway? It might be that instead of a stored proc it could be a table-valued function and that could easily be called for each row.

Comment: @mendosi (and others) - Sorry for ambiguity of the above question, the procedure is sending an email using the built in EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail.

Comment: So 1 minute to send 1000 emails? Maybe this is not a problem. I suspect that if you edit the question and include the name of the stored proc in the title you might get specific advice from someone who is familiar with sp_send_mail

Comment: @mendosi - I want to send an email for each alert. The email procedure isn't the problem (as such), the problem is I don't know how to supply the information into the email procedure without doing a loop. The loop is taking the time not the email procedure. I want to send a separate email per row in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK `sp_send_dbmail` will need to be called once for each email, so either you have a loop here or you have a loop inside `dbo.someProcedure`.

Still I think that you could make some improvements. Use a `FAST_FORWARD` cursor rather than creating iteration variables and returning to the table each time to find the next row (thus creating 1000 table scans). Don't store redundant data in your `#temp` table, only what you need. This makes the table quicker to read.

Try this:

```
--Set up a temp table with all non email alerts
Create Table #temp (VehicleID int Primary Key Clustered, ImgData varbinary(max));

INSERT INTO #temp (VehicleID, ImgData)
SELECT TOP(1000)
    a.VehicleID, i.ImgData
FROM 
    dbo.ALERTS a 
JOIN 
    dbo.IMAGES i ON i.VehicleID = a.VehicleID
WHERE 
    a.EmailImageSent = 0 OR a.EmailSent = 0;

DECLARE @VehicleID int;
DECLARE @ImgData VARBINARY(MAX);
DECLARE Alert_Cursor Cursor Fast_Forward For (
    Select VehicleID, ImgData From #temp);
OPEN Alert_Cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM Alert_Cursor INTO @VehicleID, @ImgData;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN    
    IF @ImgData IS NOT NULL
        EXEC dbo.someProcedure @VehicleID, @ImgData;

    FETCH NEXT FROM Alert_Cursor INTO @VehicleID, @ImgData;
END

CLOSE Alert_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE Alert_Cursor;

DROP TABLE #temp;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time out for this answer :)

Comment: @Tealpelican Did the performance improve? If so it will help future readers if you mark the answer as accepted, if not then I'd like to know that too.

Comment: I've added this in and unfortunately I've seen no difference in timings (a minor difference or 1:06 vs 1:08 for new vs old. I still think this is a cleaner way than my current code (selecting only specific data for temp insert etc).  I will just have to limit how many emails I wish to send maybe to a factor of 10 instead.